# What is the fastest and (or) "low cost" method to render a blob image in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, image, blob, rendering

The goal is to render on page a lot of images that comes from a few web-socket connections continiously (it's some kind of multiscreen video-supervision system) . This page may be opened in browsers of very slow devices (Android TV for example), and the perfomance must be as high as possible.

So, jpeg images comes from server as blob (or arraybuffer if to specify)... I lnow few methods to show them:

1. base64_encode to img src
2. FileReader() ... reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
3. URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([arrayBuffer]))
4. Draw in HTML5 canvas

But I have no idea how to measure their working speed and CPU resources load. Does anybody have an expirience with different methods of showing images in browser? Which one is the fastest and low costed for CPU resources?

Comment: It depends in each use case, so you have to test it for yours. _Lazy loading_ would of course be a clever way to approach  the issue when need to load a lot of images, as it saves both server and client side work load ... server: as one normally have to pay for it ... client: so user won't leave when their browser starts to lag